# how to extract features,such as color, of an image using k means algorithm in MATLAB?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, k-means

I have a data set consisting of animals . I want to identify the color of each animal using k means algorithm in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

So we have N animals and background, in an image. Presuming the background is roughly uniform, run k means on the pixels with N+1 means, one for each animal and one for the background. Pixels should the be sorted into their respective animals after kmeans converges.

To run kmeans, choose N pixels at random for your first centres. Using a distance metric, then assign a pixel to each centre (distance = abs d red + abs d green + abs d blue or similar). Then take the most central pixel of each cluster, and repeat until the algorithm is stable - none of the pixels move clusters.